# How to specify the files to overwrite using linux cp command on PHP?

Tags: php, file, copy, overwrite, cp

Is it possible to tell to linux `cp` command which files to overwrite via PHP?

Basically, I have searched the conflicts between the source and the destination folders, asked the user what files to overwrite and put them on an `array`.

Now I want to copy the files, overwriting only the files on the `array`.

Comment: You can use PHP's copy function http://php.net/copy or exec http://php.net/exec to execute system commands.

Comment: Is it better than linux `cp` command?

Comment: Preference to the PHP *copy* primitive: you stay in control from PHP (and it's more efficient)

Comment: But to use `copy` in this case, I need to make a cycle to compare each file with what is in the array right? Is it efficient?

Comment: Using `cp` you would have to check as well if the file exists and if it has to be overwritten. There is no much difference between dealing with `cp` or `copy` - but the latter is a Php primitive, doesn't create a separate process, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not call copy with only those files that need to be overwritten and exclude the files which are not to be copied?

By default cp overwrites the file, you can try the -f (force option) but that should bot be necessary.

Comment: Well, I thought that `copy` is slower than `cp`.